# What does "U2000: ($600 b/25) $250-150-100." mean?

Tags: tournament, terminology

When looking for tournaments I keep finding myself confused by abbreviations used (I just found a reference which has been slightly helpful). This one for example is from a Marshall club tournament in the coming future. I get the Under 2000 part but what about the

"($600 b/25) $250-150-100" ?

Here is the full listing:

> 6-SS, G/90 +30. Two sections. U2000: ($600 b/25) $250-150-100. U1700: $100. U1400: ($600 b/25) $250-150-100. U1100: $100. EF: $60, MCC Mbrs $40. Reg:. 6:15-6:45pm. Rds.: 7pm each Wed. Limit two byes; request by rd. 4. www.marshallchessclub.org. 23 W. 10th St., NYC. 212-477-3716.

Comment: http://www.championshipchess.net/jargon.html or http://saintlouischessclub.org/events/weekly-tournaments/tournament-terms-ratings-and-information gives full details of what the abbreviations mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on ("b/") 25 entries in the section, its total prize pool will be $600. That money will be distributed as $250 for first place, $150 for second place, $100 for third place, and $100 for the top-finishing player under 1700 in the under 2000 section.

If there are more than 25 entries, the prize pool will be larger, and the prizes for each place will likely be adjusted proportionally. Likewise, the prize pool will be smaller if there are under 25 entries.